# Insert PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image into PowerPoint

Tags: python-pptx

I'd like to open an image using PIL, make some changes to it and then insert it into a PowerPoint slide. Below is my code:

```
from PIL import Image 
# Open the image
im1 = Image.open(imPath)
## Make some changes 
im2 = add_corners(im1, 50)
## Insert into slide
im3 = slide.shapes.add_picture(im2,
                               left=Cm(1),
                               top=Cm(1),
                               height=Cm(3.25))
```

However, when I do this, I get `AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'`.

To get it around it, I have been saving `im2` somewhere and then providing the path to it in when inserting it into PowerPoint, but this doesn't seem like the best strategy. Is it possible to insert it straight in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shapes.add_picture()` does not accept a PIL image. It only accepts actual saved formats like JPEG or PNG. You can provide these as a BytesIO object so there is no need for a temporary file. Just save the PIL image to a BytesIO object and then feed that (after calling `seek(0)` on it) to `.add_picture()` like so.

```
import io

image = add_corners(Image.open(imPath), 50)
image_stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(image_stream, "PNG")
image_stream.seek(0)
picture = slide.shapes.add_picture(image_stream, left, top)
```

Comment: What is the `image_file` variable?

Comment: Should it be `image_stream` in its place instead?